# Why $S=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$ is normal?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

> Let $(A_1,\cdots,A_n)\in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$ be such that
>
> - $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ for all $i,j$.
> - $A_k^*A_k=A_kA_k^*$ for all $k$.
>
> Why $S=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$ is normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each $A_j$ is normal, and $A_i,\ A_j$ commute for all $i,j$, so by the Fuglede-Putnam-Rosenblum theorem, we have $A_i^*A_j=A_jA_i^*$ for all $i,j$.

Knowing this, we have 
$$S^*S=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^*\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^nA_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_i^*A_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_jA_i^*=SS^*$$

Comment: Could you please give  me More details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: More details about what?

Comment: How to show that S is normal? I don't  understand when we use the  commutativity..thank you

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very  much

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

That $S$ is normal is a consequence of $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ for $i,j$, the normality of all $A_k$ and Fuglede's theorem .

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem)